# Using Java-to-schema mapped object as Freemarker data model

Tags: java, xml, annotations, freemarker

Background:
I have a webservice that previously only received requests for xml, but now needs to return html for browser access.
I have a Java class that is mapped to XML with the XmlRootElement annotation.

I am using Freemarker to generate HTML based on this Java class, but cannot find a way to do so directly.

At the moment I use NodeModel.parse to parse the xml to a freemarker datamodel, but since the NodeModel.parse takes a File, I first write the Java object to a file. That is obviously an inefficient way to do it, but it does the job.

Does anyone know a way to go get a freemarker datamodel out of a this Java class without first writing it to an XML file?

The following is my code:

The Java-to-Schema mapped class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "report")
public class Report {
    private String id;  
    private String time;    

    public Report() {}

    public String getTime() {return time;}
    public void setTime(String time) {this.time = time;}

    public String getId() {return this.id;}    
    public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}    
}
```

Merging the data with the template:

```
public String getReportsAsHtml(@QueryParam("lastUpdate") String lastUpdate){
    MySQLAccess dao = new MySQLAccess();
    List<Report> reports = dao.readReports(lastUpdate);
Template  temp = TemplateConfiguration.getInstance().getTemplateConfiguration().getTemplate("list_template.ftl");
    **HashMap<String, NodeModel> root = new HashMap<String, NodeModel>();**
    **root.put("doc", NodeModel.parse(Java2XML.getXMLFromJava(reports)));**
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    temp.process(root, output);
    output.flush();
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Since you already had the XML, you could use XSLT to output HTML or just about anything.

Comment: I don't already have the XML. I have a list of objects annotated with Schema-to-Java annotation.

Comment: I meant that you already have the generation code for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeModel` has a `wrap(org.w3c.dom.Node)` method, so you surely don't have to create an XML file. All you need is a tree of `org.w3c.dom.Node` objects, and FreeMarker doesn't care where it comes from. Actually, if you are using the default object-wrapper of FreeMarker, you don't even need to deal with `NodeModel`, just drop the `org.w3c.dom.Node` into the data model as any other POJO, and FreeMarker will recognize it as XML.

Also note that FreeMarker has this `ObjectWrapper` abstraction. It separates the actual objects from how they are seen from the templates. So you possibly doesn't even need to make a tree of `Node`-s from those objects, just make an `ObjectWrapper` implementation that directly understands those annotated object. See how `DefaultObjectWrapper` extends `BeansWrapper`, automatically wrapping `Node`-s, Jython object, etc. You can follow the same pattern. But of course writing your own `ObjectWrapper` is extra work, especially if you need XPath support too (hint: Jaxen doesn't need `Node`-s).

Comment: Thanks. The point is that I already have a tree structure in the form of a POJO annotated with Java-to-Schema annotations, and I was hoping that FreeMarker would be able to recognize this structure. In lack of that, would you expand on how I get a tree of Node objects to drop into the data model?

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't recognize those annotations out-of-the-box, but, as I said, it's extendable to do that. So, how you get a tree of `Node`-s from those POJO-s also falls outside FreeMarker's out-of-the-box functionality. The thing that creates XML files from them can't return a tree of `Node`-s instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code to generate a Node tree from a Java-to-Schema annotated class:

```
public static Node getNodeFromReport(Object report){
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(report.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document result = docFac.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

    marshaller.marshal(report, result);

    return result;
}
```